# Get Document By Id using CouchDB and Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, couchdb

I am trying to follow a similar work flow as others using Backbone and CouchDB. If my connector looks like this:

```
Backbone.couch_connector.config.db_name = window.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
Backbone.couch_connector.config.ddoc_name = window.location.pathname.split("/")[3];
Backbone.couch_connector.config.global_changes = false;
```

And my URL has the document _id, whats the cleanest way to get a document?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Define a route in your [backbone router](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-routes) that passes the id to a function
2. In the function instantiate the model, setting the passed in `id`
3. Call `fetch()` on the model

   ```
   routes: {
       '/foo/:id' : 'doFoo'
   }

   doFoo = function(id) {
       doc = new Model({ '_id' : id }).fetch();            
   }
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuTAK/1/